# How do you add USE INDEX (indexname) to ObjectionJS query

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I have a select statement:

```
const myObject = await MyObject 
.query()
.eager('foo')
.eager('foo.bar')
.omit(['some_big_data']) // Skip the giant field to improve performance/memory
.where('when_created', '>', '2019-09-01')
.whereNotNull('player_details')
.whereNull('region_id')
.limit(10000);
```

This results in the following SQL:

```
select `foo`.*
from `foo` 
where `when_created` > '2019-09-01'
and `player_details` is not null
and `region_id` is null
limit 1000;
```

I want to add the SQL `use index (my_index)` to the query, so it becomes:

```
select `foo`.*
from `foo` 
use index (my_index)
where `when_created` > '2019-09-01'
and `player_details` is not null
and `region_id` is null
limit 1000;
```

Is this possible to do in ObjectionJS, or do I need to drop to a raw query?

Answer (score 0):

Knex 0.20 nor objection has any support for doing that. You need to write raw query to make it happen.